# How to load data lazily in Django admin list page

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a lot of annotations in admin page by customizing `def get_queryset(self, request: HttpRequest) -> QuerySet:` in `ModelAdmin` and using them in `list_display`. This has made admin page loading extremely slow. Is there a way to load the annotated fields lazily for each row in django admin list page? For example I rewrite the `get_queryset` and load the other data separately for each row lazily.

I appreciate any help or idea:)

Comment: you can implement pagination and override in admin.py

Comment: I know this method, but this approach doesn't solve the inherent problem

Comment: how large is your dataset? are you using any cache?